# Hypersurfaces considered as Cartier divisors and linear equivalence

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I'm trying to understand the notion of Cartier divisors and I am having trouble understanding the connection with hypersurfaces in the projective space $\mathbb{P}^n_k$, where $k$ is an algebraically closed field.
So the definition of Cartier divisors says that such a divisor is defined by an open cover and for each open set $U_i$ a function $f_i \in K^*$, where $K$ is the function field of $\mathbb{P}^n_k$ s.t. we can glue these $f_i$ along the intersections of open sets $U_i$ and $U_j$. If we now choose a homogeneous polynomial $f \in \mathcal{O}(d)$ of degree $d$, we get a hypersurface $H$ of degree $d$ and $f$ gives us a Cartier divisor. Now apparently any other hypersurface $H'$ (given by some $g$) of degree $d$ is linearly equivalent to $H$. I am having trouble seeing how this works as we would have $H' = H + (g/f)$ but $g/f$ is not a regular function on all of $\mathbb{P}^n_k$. Obviously this is not how it works but where is my mistake? Thanks for any help!

Comment: There are very few regular functions on all of $\mathbb{P}^n$ (only constants), and you only need $g/f$ to be a rational function on $\mathbb{P}^n$ (you certainly need to consider the poles of $g/f$ as well when thinking about linear equivalence).

Comment: Could you elaborate what you mean by "you certainly need to consider the poles of $g/f$ as well when thinking about linear equivalence" in this context? I see that $g/f$ is a rational function but the fact that this function does have poles is exactly why I don't see how linear equivalence works here.

Comment: Linear equivalence in this case means that $H' - H$ should be the divisor of some rational function. In this case, $g/f$ vanishes exactly at $H'$ and has poles exactly at $H$ (with the right order), so $div(g/f)$ is exactly $H' - H$.

Comment: Right I think that makes sense to me. Thanks so much!